# C# How to Compare a letter or letters to another string

Tags: c#, string, search, compare, substring

So I'm making a hangman game to practise my C# skills but I've hit a bump I cannot figure out how to loop through the randomly chosen word and compare the users choice from the textbox. I know how to grab the users input and convert it into a variable string. But not how to compare it and remove the * and replace it with the currect letter.

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace Guess_The_Word
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private int wrongGuesses = 0;
        private int userGuesses;
        private string secretWord = String.Empty;
        private string[] words;
        private string currentWord = string.Empty;
        private string userGuess = string.Empty;


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string path = (@"C:\commonwords.txt"); // Save the variable path with the path to the txt file
            words = File.ReadAllLines(path);
            int guessIndex = (new Random()).Next(words.Length);
            currentWord = words[guessIndex];

            char[] currentWordCharArray = currentWord.ToCharArray();

            foreach (char c in currentWordCharArray)
            {
                currentWord.Contains(userInputBox.Text);

                wordlbl.Text += "*";
            }



        }

        private void guessBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }


        private void resetGamebtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: looks like you probably need to convert the user input into a char array as well, then compare the first index of your random word to the the first index of the user input box and do the same for the others.

Comment: I've turned the user guess into char array, what method would I use to compare two char arrays in that manner?

Comment: Maybe I'm jumping in to far, or I need to think and look back at it tomorrow.

Comment: I guess the question is are you checking the whole word at once?, or your are doing letter by letter inputed?, what is the user inputing a letter or a word?

Comment: Added an example below so you have an example to build from

Comment: I dont think you want to use the Form Load event to check the user input, seeing as no user input would ever be there since this is the event that literally loads the Form...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If so:

```
char a = 'x';
char b = 'y';
```

Then you can use an if statement like, `if (a == b)` and you can use this result as output like list of boolean that correct answers places.

You need to loop currentWordCharArray and check userInputCharArray(which is converted ToCharArray) and need to be sure that you're not checking for out userInputCharArray. I mean currentWordCharArray can have 7 letter and you can show char count of correct word, anyway user can use an input word that not have 7 letter. After all collect trues and falses to show which letter is right.

Edit:

```
private void guessBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        char[] currentWordCharArray = currentWord.ToCharArray();
        char[] userGuessCharArray = userInputBox.Text.ToCharArray();
        int lengthOfAnswer = currentWordCharArray.Length;
        List<char> progressInformer = new List<char>();

        for (int i = 0; i < lengthOfAnswer; i++)
        {
            if (i < userGuessCharArray.Length)
            {
                if (currentWordCharArray[i] == userGuessCharArray[i])
                {
                    progressInformer.Add(currentWordCharArray[i]);
                }
                else
                {
                    progressInformer.Add('*');
                }
            }
            else
            {
                progressInformer.Add('*');
            }
        }
    }
```

The loop you couldn't imagine is above. progressInformer will contain true letter if guessed correctly in right place, else wild char(mean '*') for wrong letter. For example; if your system select 'italic' as word and user guessed 'italy' then progressInformer will be a list of char which is something like

```
List<char> progressInformer = new List<char> { 'i', 't', 'a', 'l', '*', '*' };
```

Any unenlightened part of my solution?

Cheers!

Comment: So I do need a for loop, just need to think of how to implement it. That char idea is good but it's very long and unneeded but I may need to do that. Since I can't even think how  to loop through and index

Comment: @LiamVallance hey I give you an hand. Please check it out and let me know if there's something wrong. Don't forget to mark it as answer if works for you.

Comment: Sadly still trying to get it through my thick brain.
This bit is odd to me since loops as you can tell confuse me if (currentWordCharArray[i] == userGuessToCharArray[i]) not sure why that works what does the i do?

Comment: So, you need to learn more about arrays and if statements. You should know that currentWordCharArray[0] is equal to a char which is the first letter in your array. 
On the other hand you can compare two char with == and != statements just like comparing two integers equality and inequality.

Comment: I know about == its the foor loop I don't understand. WHat is the i doing in the loop? Changing its number and comparing?

Comment: Also, for (int i = 0; i < lengthOfAnswer; i++) means it'll repeat for from 0 to lengthOfAnswer which equals to length of selected answer by your code.
i -> 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 for the sample 'italic' and then you do:
if (currentWordCharArray[0] == userGuessCharArray[0])
if (currentWordCharArray[1] == userGuessCharArray[1]) so on...
This let you compare the letter at the same index if there's enough letter.

Comment: To my understanding the for loop is looping through each index thus looping through each char[] array

Comment: By the way, make sure that userGuess is not longer than currentWord just because of avoiding from false positive.
If you don't check that one you can sey correct word for italica when italic selected one.

Comment: I'm still confused what the for loops i really does on if (currentWordCharArray[i] == userGuessCharArray[i]) I don't know what the i is doing, I know for arrays you use [] to find the index

Comment: i is the variable to count loop's repeat time. for(int i = 0; i < lengthOfAnswer; i++) means i will be increased by one from 0 to be until equal to lengthOfAnswer. i is the counter for another word. As I told you earlier.

Comment: I understand what i is, I just don't understand how it helps compare the words maybe doing it the way you said by using there index and using if statements will be the way tho its very messy I'm sure the more cleaner version will be more complex maybe its just me being slow

Comment: exactly. you need to get 1st, 2nd, ... element(letter/char) of the choosen word and guessed word. i stands for help you to access correct data of the array.

Comment: Thank you, I'll tackle this now and start from scratch as I understand more. I can use a for loop to compare each element from the userguess to the word

Answer (score 2):

Here is a console app with an example, you can build from here. This does not do the replacement of the * for you or exactly what you intend to do, but it will help you as a start point.

```
using System;

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            string randomInput = "Apple";
            string userInput = "Apple";


            //Word lengths are not equal therefore user has lost already
            if(randomInput.Length != userInput.Length){
                Console.WriteLine("User has not guessed the word, your word is not the same size as the random one.");
                return;
            }


            char[] randomCharArray = randomInput.ToLowerInvariant().ToCharArray();
            char[] userInputArray = userInput.ToLowerInvariant().ToCharArray();

            for(int i = 0; i < randomCharArray.Length; i++)
            {
                if(randomCharArray[i] == userInputArray[i])
                    continue;
                else{
                    Console.WriteLine("You have not guessed the word, keep trying!");
                    return;
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("You have won!, you have guessed the word {0}",userInput));

        }

    }
```

Comment: Currently having issues showing the * for each letter of the word
            foreach (char c in currentWord)
            {
                displaylbl.Text = "*";
            }